# initial problem ODE solve with Laplace Transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Consider the initial value problem:

$$x''(t) +3x'(t)+2x(t)= t + (ae^{-(t-a)}-t) H(t-a)$$ $$x(0)=0$$ $$x'(0)=0$$ where $a>0$ is constant and $H$ is the Heaviside function.

Let $f(t)=t + (ae^{-(t-a)}-t) H(t-a)$. Applying the Laplace transformation with $ \mathcal{L \{x(t) \}}=X(s)$ and $\mathcal{L \{f(t) \} } =F(s)$, and using the initial conditions, and after some calculation we get:

$X(s) =\dfrac{F(s)}{(s+1)(s+2)}$, from which we get $x(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{\dfrac{F(s)}{(s+1)(s+2)} \right\}$.

And so it is the case that:
$$x(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{\frac{F(s)}{s+1} \right\}  -\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{\frac{F(s)}{s+2} \right\}  = e^{-t}*f(t) - e^{-2t}*f(t)= e^{-t}(1-e^{-t})*f(t)$$

where $*$ is the operator of convolution.

How can I continue now to do as few calculations as possible?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I am interested also if there is a simpler way (using Laplace Transformation). Tell me.

Comment: Cannot you explicitly calculate $F(s)$, and use its expression for the anti-transformation, instead of using convolution?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to compute the convolution integral in the $s$-plane. Not in the time plane.  Use the identity:
$$\mathcal{L\{f(t)\ast  g(t)\}}=\mathcal{L \left\{\int_o^tf(t-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau \right\} } =F(s)G(s),$$ where $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ are the Laplace transforms of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off just evaluating the inverse directly.  That is, evaluate $F(s)$ and divide by $(s+1)(s+2)$, and then use a table or evaluate the Bromwich contour in the complex $s$ plane to get $x(t)$.

You compute $F(s)$ from

$$\begin{align}F(s) &= \int_0^{\infty} dt \: [t + (a e^{t-a}-t) H(t-a)] e^{-s t}\\ &= \frac{1-e^{-a s}}{s^2}  + a \frac{e^{-a s}}{s+1} - a \frac{e^{-a s}}{s} \end{align}$$

(Please check my work, although I do believe I am correct.)

The LT of the solution is then

$$X(s) = \frac{F(s)}{(s+1)(s+2)} = \frac{1-e^{-a s}}{s^2 (s+1)(s+2)}  + a \frac{e^{-a s}}{(s+1)^2 (s+2)} - a \frac{e^{-a s}}{s(s+1)(s+2)}$$

The ILT of this is straightforward, if a little messy.